# Error while using sudo on the base user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, nautilus

I am having an issue when I try to run

```
sudo -u user nautilus
```

in the terminal. It will not run the command as user and ends up running a weird messed up version of `nautilus` with most root permissions. It continuously throws the error:

> ```
> unable to create file '/home/user/.cache/dconf/user': Permission denied. dconf will not work properly.
> ```

When I check the file it is trying to create, it does in fact exist. I am using the OS Ubuntu 17.04. Running the command as root reaps the same results and the user does have access to the folder.

Comment: Does the user have the permissions on the folder you pointed out is indicating the user is unable to create the file in?  Additionally the user has which Sudo permissions.  If you use root instead of the user does it work?  Update your question don’t submit a comment

Comment: While updating the question to answer Ramhound's comment please note that posting the output of `ls -ld /home/user/.cache/dconf/ /home/user/.cache/dconf/user` is better than just stating 'yes, the user has the permissions' or 'no, ...'.